# Why does IKEv2 forbid dynamic address updates for hosts behind NAT?

Tags: ipsec, ddos, ikev2

In [RFC7296, Section 2.23](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7296#section-2.23) it is written:

> There are cases where a NAT box decides to remove mappings that are
> still alive (for example, the keepalive interval is too long, or the
> NAT box is rebooted). ... A host behind a NAT SHOULD NOT do this type
> of dynamic address update if a validated packet has different port
> and/or address values because it opens a possible DoS attack (such as
> allowing an attacker to break the connection with a single packet).

I cannot quite understand what kind of attack a host behind a NAT is more vulnerable to.

My current best guess is an attack on a NAT device with the intent to overwrite existing mapping. But if such attack is found, it will break the connection regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the entire paragraph. They're talking about how to handle a dynamic address changing mid-connection, which could be due to a NAT timeout, NAT table reset ("reboot"), or the node simply getting a new address.

```
... This will be apparent to a host if
it receives a packet whose integrity protection validates, but has
a different port, address, or both from the one that was
associated with the SA in the validated packet. When such a
validated packet is found, a host that does not support other
methods of recovery such as IKEv2 Mobility and Multihoming
(MOBIKE) [MOBIKE], and that is not behind a NAT...
... (that is, they SHOULD dynamically update the address).
```

The key part that is "*that is not behind NAT*". (i.e. NAT-T has not detected NAT) A host *behind* NAT should not update anything to avoid the possibility of nefarious actors breaking the connection, because many common NAT routers can be rather dumb in handling UDP traffic -- it's easy to spoof UDP, and a simple router might let it through.

Comment: My question is not about what shouldt be done, that’s clear per RFC. It is about specifics of the attack. Say another peer’s NAT is reset and a new packet arrives from a different address/port pair. What property of a receiver w/o NAT allows it handle it properly, I do not see what information is lost during the translation.

Answer (score 2):

If implemented as specified, the host without NAT will always be able to receive messages from the host behind the NAT once the attack stops. That is, the connection fixes itself.

However, if the host behind the NAT would also update address/port dynamically, the host without NAT might not be able to reach it anymore once the original NAT mapping timed out and the host behind the NAT sends further packets to a different endpoint.

Also consider that if both updated addresses dynamically, an attacker, depending on where it's located, might be able to use a single IKEv2 request/response pair or two ESP packets in both directions to redirect traffic of these hosts irrecoverably for the lifetime of the IKE_SA (i.e. until DPD tears down the connection and the host behind the NAT uses the original server address again to recreate the IKE_SA).

Obviously depends on the NAT's mapping and filtering behavior if it's even possible to send a message with a different source IP/port through the NAT.

Comment: My understanding is that DoS can be achieved regardless of NAT: the attacker only needs to intercept a valid packet from the sender (validity check) and be first to deliver it (new packet check). And it should do so continuously. Per the RFC, presence of a NAT in front of the receiver somehow makes such attack orders of magnitude cheaper, single-packet even. But how? Assuming NAT allows packets from a different IP/port through, retaining internal mapping, then a rewrite is not permanent and once attack stops legitimate host will be able to reach receiver again, just like an attacker was.

Comment: If an attacker can do this continuously, you can't avoid getting DoSed (it could probably also just drop the packets). I think the idea was that it would somehow be possible to get a packet to the host behind the NAT from a different IP/port and that the original mapping would then time out. But I agree with you that doing that from outside the NAT seems unlikely. But it could be possible from within the NAT (maybe in an open Wi-Fi or in some CGN setup) and two packets would still be enough from outside the NAT (i.e. by redirecting both hosts).

Comment: That's seems like the most plausible explanation. But I wonder if the authors implicitly referred some well-known problem with NAT implementations at the time when this RFC was written.